# IE 10 Selecting a link does not return correct parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

I have a function that returns the parent element of selection when text is selected using mouse.

Javascript

```
$("#p1").on('mouseup',function(evt){
 var selectedParentElement = null,range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  if (rangeSelectsSingleNode(range)) {
        selectedParentElement = range.startContainer.childNodes[range.startOffset];
  } else if (range.startContainer.nodeType === 3) {
       selectedParentElement = range.startContainer.parentNode;
  } else {
     selectedParentElement = range.startContainer;
  }
  console.log(selectedParentElement);
})

function rangeSelectsSingleNode(range) {
    var startNode = range.startContainer;
    return startNode === range.endContainer &&
           startNode.hasChildNodes() &&
          range.endOffset === range.startOffset + 1;
}
```

In chrome and firefox when i select the link inside contenteditable paragraph, the function returns correct parent node i.e. `<a>` but in IE 10 it returns parent element as 'paragraph'

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/THPmr/244/)

Comment: @madalinivascu jQuery parent returns immediate parent element, it has nothing to do with ranges

Answer (score 1):

The reason is reasonably easy to find if you examine the selected range: when you select the link text in IE, the end boundary is at the end of the text node in the link, as you expected, while the start boundary is at the end of the text node preceding the link, which is not what you expect. This is fairly common: browsers have different ideas about which positions within the document are valid for selection boundaries.

A simple fix for this case (but not more general case with more complicated HTML) is to check if the range start boundary is at the end of a text node and move it to the start of the text node within the next element:

```
function adjustRangeStart(range) {
    var node = range.startContainer;
    var offset = range.startOffset;
    var nextNode, nextNodeChild;

    if (   node.nodeType == 3 &&
           offset == node.length &&
           (nextNode = node.nextSibling) &&
           nextNode.nodeType == 1 &&
           (nextNodeChild = nextNode.firstChild) &&
           nextNodeChild.nodeType == 3) {

        range.setStart(nextNodeChild, 0);
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/THPmr/248/